# OSSEC New Install: Scan and analyse full log?

Tags: ids, logging

When OSSEC is installed and started, it starts analyzing configured logs starting the date it was installed. Is there a way to have it scan and analyze the full logs?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain it will automatically, as its core purpose is real-time alerting and active response.

In saying that, you can run manual log analysis on any log file. The instructions at http://ossec-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/programs/ossec-logtest.html give guidance on configuring log analysis. You just need to provide the name of the file to be monitored.  For example:

```
# cat /var/log/access.log | /var/ossec/bin/ossec-logtest -a
```